# Looking for suggestions on how to improve my CNN model - how much loss is too much?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I've played around with the setup of my architecture a lot, the number of layers, pooling size, dropouts, etc but I always end up in the same ballpark: ~96-98 accuracy and loss between 2-6%.

I'm training from a dataset of 78000 images, 26 classes (letters of the alphabet), and 3000 images per photo. I am satisfied with the accuracy, but are there any suggestions to reduce loss? Also How much loss do you think is too much? Anything else I should add to the model to make it more robust?  Code for the model is shown below:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 1))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 1))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 1))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(26, activation='softmax'))
```

Compile and Fit:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Output:

```
Train on 54600 samples, validate on 23400 samples
Epoch 1/10
54600/54600 [==============================] - 68s 1ms/step - loss: 1.1217 - accuracy: 0.6622 - val_loss: 0.9795 - val_accuracy: 0.7394
Epoch 2/10
54600/54600 [==============================] - 67s 1ms/step - loss: 0.2377 - accuracy: 0.9219 - val_loss: 0.2300 - val_accuracy: 0.9277
Epoch 3/10
54600/54600 [==============================] - 67s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1184 - accuracy: 0.9627 - val_loss: 0.2746 - val_accuracy: 0.9286
Epoch 4/10
54600/54600 [==============================] - 67s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0755 - accuracy: 0.9761 - val_loss: 0.1850 - val_accuracy: 0.9517
Epoch 5/10
54600/54600 [==============================] - 69s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0669 - accuracy: 0.9801 - val_loss: 0.2044 - val_accuracy: 0.9450
Epoch 6/10
54600/54600 [==============================] - 69s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0520 - accuracy: 0.9848 - val_loss: 0.2265 - val_accuracy: 0.9485
Epoch 7/10
54600/54600 [==============================] - 72s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0481 - accuracy: 0.9865 - val_loss: 0.1709 - val_accuracy: 0.9559
Epoch 8/10
54600/54600 [==============================] - 66s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0370 - accuracy: 0.9905 - val_loss: 0.1534 - val_accuracy: 0.9659
Epoch 9/10
54600/54600 [==============================] - 66s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0335 - accuracy: 0.9912 - val_loss: 0.1181 - val_accuracy: 0.9703
Epoch 10/10
54600/54600 [==============================] - 66s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0277 - accuracy: 0.9921 - val_loss: 0.1204 - val_accuracy: 0.9704
```

Comment: Is your dataset some commonly used one, or did you make it? Have you looked at some of the misidentified pictures if there's something in common?

Comment: It's an American Sign Language dataset from kaggle, 78000 images. I did not make it myself. There are nothing common about the misidentified photos from what I can tell.